# Adding filter to one hearder column of the Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to create a filter to one of my header column [Carrier] , here is the code of  gridview that I've created:

**index.aspx:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cr_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                 DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CARRIER" DataValueField="CARRIER"> 
             </asp:DropDownList>
             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MybaseConnectionString %>" 
                 SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [CARRIER] FROM [TABLE]">
                 </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="284px">
</asp:GridView>
```

**index.aspx.vb**

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim cx As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Mybase;Integrated Security=True;")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            cmd.Connection = cx
            cmd.CommandText = "select cl1, Carrier, cl2, cl3 from table"
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Sub

   Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

Any one can help Please!
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

take one textbox

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch"/>
```

on button click event

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            cmd.Connection = cx
            cmd.CommandText = "select cl1, Carrier, cl2, cl3 from table where Carrier='"+txtSearch.Text+"'"
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Sub
```

Comment: This will open db to SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting a drop down list in the header of the column you wish to filter (in your case Carrier). Then you can wire up the OnSelectedIndexChanged event of the drop down list to handle the actual filtering of your column's data. An older, but still relevant example of this technique is here:

[ASP.NET GridView Column Filtering](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Asp.Net_GridView_Filter.aspx)

Comment: The drop down list should be filled automatically from the database, You can see the edited post, But how I can the rest? Can you help please !

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided, there is an example in there of using values from a database, you will want to build a SELECT DISTINCT query to get a list of all the choices the user can make for Carrier, or you could hard-code them if they are constant; are these phone line carriers or something else?

Comment: Carriers are the different names of shipping company! The gridView does not display all the carriers it depends on user needs, so the list should not contain all the choices, it should contain just the carriers that are shown in the gridView!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Carrier is field of type nvarchar(200) and filtering should be done after user clicks on Button1 (which is not visible in markup), body of method Button1_Click should look like:

```
    Dim sql As String = "select cl1, Carrier, cl2, cl3 from table where Carrier = @Carrier"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Mybase;Integrated Security=True;"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Carrier", SqlDbTypes.NVarChar, 200).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

      da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
      da.Fill(dt)
      GridView1.DataSource = dt
      GridView1.DataBind()
    End Using
```

Comment: the drop down list should be related to the header column[Carrier] of the gridview

Answer (score 0):

You might are in need to look at `RowFilter` property of `DataGrid`. Have a look at [this link](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Asp.Net_GridView_Filter.aspx), which include sample code.

Comment: I didn't find rowFilter in the Gridview properties

Comment: See this part: `DataView dv = GetAllCustomers();` and `dv.RowFilter = condition;`